# Javascript function document.createElement(tagName[, options]) doesn't work as intended

Tags: javascript

I need to create `<a href="http://someurl.com"></a>` element **in one js code line**

this doesn't work:

`var gg = document.createElement("a", {href : "http://someurl.com"})`

this result in: `<a is="[object Object]"></a>`

Thought MDN says:
`var element = document.createElement(tagName[, options]);`

options is an optional ElementCreationOptions object. If this object is defined and has an `is` property, the `is` attribute of the created element is initalized with the value of this property. If the object has no `is` property, the value is null.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

is this ElementCreationOptions object some sort of exotic object? I tried many various combinations around this object but nothing works and always in results i see that strange `is` property! I also found it in specification: https://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/#attr-is but no idea how it actually works.

ps:
this doesn't work either:

`var gg = document.createElement("a").setAttribute("href" , "someurl.com")`

result in undefined.

Comment: `options` is not an object of attributes.

Comment: Why do you need to do it in one command?

Comment: Just use `var gg = document.createElement("div"); gg.setAttribute("href" , "someurl.com");`. If you need it as a single expression, put it in a helper function and call that.

Comment: You need to read the documentation more carefully. "If this object is defined and has an "is" property, **the "is" attribute of the created element is initalized with the value of this property**." It doesn't say anywhere that the options object initializes arbitrary element attributes.

Comment: Note you document.createElement("**div**") not "**a**" - Do this on 2 lines and it will do what you want. (`setAttribute` does not return the element to `gg`)

Comment: @Frxstrem: it's just challenging task. i know my collegue can do it in one line of code and i want to know how :)


@bergi what is `options` then? MDN says it is an object

Comment: I've read the documentation and the line 'If this object is defined and has an "is" property, the "is" attribute of the created element is initalized with the value of this property' and I had no idea what it means. The answers to this question explain it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27434431/what-is-html-is-attribute. Hint: the "is" property of HTML elements is a proposed property that's never been implemented. The idea, as I gather, was to allow users to add a super class to elements.

Answer (score 34):

I get that this is an ancient question (relatively), and @Luke-Weaver's answer already gave a route involving jQuery, but the following is an option that both accomplishes what @Garegin originally requested, while still giving him the functionality that he wanted from the createElement method's ambiguous parameter name, while using vanilla JS.

```
gg = Object.assign(document.createElement('a'),{href:'http://someurl.com',innerText:"Bonus points?"});
```

This solution creates `'<a href="http://someurl.com">Bonus points?</a>'` on one line. It's longer, so the following might work better:

```
function oneLineTag(tag,options){
  return Object.assign(document.createElement(tag),options);
}
let quickAnchor = {
  href:'http://someurl.com',
  innerText: "I'm still answering a 3-year-old question"
}
```

and you now have the option of

```
gg = oneLineTag('a',quickAnchor);
```

Comment: Key of `class` does not seem to work inside of the second parameter and I'm not sure why.

Comment: You need to use the key "className" in the second parameter. It's a single string, space delimited. You can later interact with that as an element by interacting with either that string, or with the classList property that provides an array-like construct with some helpful methods. ClassName at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className ClassList at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Answer (score 2):

You can not use the second ( ElementCreationOptions ) parameter to add html attributes.

```
var element = document.createElement(tagName[, options]);
```

It's clearly mentioned in the documentation that the second optional parameter is an object containing single property i.e. is. As we can see below,

> An optional ElementCreationOptions object containing a single property named is, whose value is the tag name for a custom element previously defined using customElements.define(). For backwards compatibility with previous versions of the Custom Elements specification, some browsers will allow you to pass a string here instead of an object, where the string's value is the custom element's tag name. See Extending native HTML elements for more information on how to use this parameter.

And coming to your question, the solution can be as below,

```
var body = document.body || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
var anchor = document.createElement('a');
anchor.href = 'http://someurl.com';

var text = document.createTextNode("http://someurl.com");  
anchor.appendChild(text);
body.appendChild(anchor);
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: OP wants it in one line

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will help anyone

```
((a) => !(a.href = '#link-here') || a )(document.createElement('a'))
```

**Step by step**

We just start from anonymous function which invokes itself with param

```
((param) => /* do some with arg */)(initParam)
```

Next we initialize an **A** element and do some with it

```
((LinkElement) => /* do some with new element */)(document.createElement('a'))
```

And finally we add href attribute to link like

```
!(a.href = '#link-here') || a
```

First we add href in **()**. It's return us href value and if it's not false we return **a** element with this changes by **||**

Answer (score 0):

I wanted this functionality too, but found "option" in createElement is not for this. So, I made my own createElement function.

```
function createElement(name, options) {
    let element = document.createElement(name);
    for (let key in options) {
        element.setAttribute(key, options[key]);
    }
    return element;
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
let main = document.getElementById("main");
let input_object = {
    type: "text",
    id: "id-1",
    name: "name",
    class: "cell",
    placeholder: "123456",
    min: "5",
    max: "50",
};

main.appendChild(createElement("input", input_object));
```

This will return html element with attributes set. You just need to append it to some other element. You can also reuse `input_object` by changing some of values of attributes and use it again to create new html element.

```
input_object.id = "id-2";
input_object.placeholder = "9874563"
input_object.readOnly = "";
main.appendChild(createElement("input", input_object));

input_object.id = "name-4";
input_object.placeholder = "qwertyu"
delete input_object.readOnly;
main.appendChild(createElement("input", input_object));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try it this way.

```
var gg = document.createElement("div")
 document.body.appendChild(gg);
var att = document.createAttribute( "href" );
att.value = "someurl.com" ;
gg.setAttributeNode(att);
```

Comment: yes that's probably will work. i also can make it work in two lines of code, but as i marked in question i need to do it in single line.

Answer (score -2):

I believe the second parameter of the create element function only applies to custom elements only. Instead you could use the .attr of jQuery to create/set attribute like so:

```
var gg = $(document.createElement("div")).attr("href", "someurl.com");
```

If you're not using jquery you might be out of luck (at least if you're trying to get it all on one line). I would have said to use .setAttribute() however I noticed you can't chain that to the end of an object constructor and haven't found a way around this yet.