# is and className attributes not working together on a react element

Tags: reactjs

If you go to the [React home page](https://facebook.github.io/react/) and add the attribute `className='button'` to the first example "A Simple Component" you should get this result:

[image: react 1]
*(i.e. the div with "Hello Jane" now looks like a button)*

If you also add the attribute `is='super-nice-button'` you should get this result:
[image: react 2]
*(i.e. the button styling is gone)*

Why you ask? Seems when you combine `className` with `is` react doesn't generate a `class` attribute on the resulting dom node instead it generates a `classname` (which obviously has no meaning for the browser). Watch the difference below.

With only the `class` attribute:
[image: react3]

With both the `class` and the `is` attributes:
[image: react4]

**My question:** Why does react generate `classname` and not `class` when using the `is` attribute on a react element (and essentially destroying all styling)?

*(background: I'm using inline-styling (or [Fela](http://fela.js.org/)) and I like to use the `is` attribute to tag my divs/panels so I can easily see the flow of components when clicking "Inspect Element" without having to tab over to the "React devtools". I understand it's kind of a hack but `is` is a supported attribute in React and HTML and it's a nice short word :) )*

Comment: It could be that since `is` isn't a valid element attribute, the parser notices that and skips all parsing on the element. Purely speculation mind.

Comment: `is` actually is a supported HTML attribute in React: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html

Comment: I see, thanks, ignore my comment OP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is likely related to this:

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4933

You'll need to set `class` instead of `className` if you're pretending it's a WebComponent.

Personally I'd go a different route, still have it processed like a React component, and do it in a different way, or just use the React devtools.

---

FWIW, this answer was researched on-the-fly. For future reference, here's the flow:

1) Verified behavior using a basic React JSX fiddle. Confirmed.

2) Searched for the `is` HTML attribute, which led here within first few links:

[What is HTML "is" attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27434431/438992)

3) Looking in the W3C docs I learned the name of what `is` is used for. Then I searched for "react components w3c custom elements" which led quickly to:

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4933

4) Verified using `class` instead of `className` on WebComponent-like DOM, same fiddle.

So from complete ignorance and some surprise I'd say I found the answer in about five minutes.

Comment: even if this answer were incorrect, my upvote stays purely for the on-the-fly research and explanation of said research.

Comment: @CarlMarkham Thanks :) I do that sometimes to help people develop a trouble-shooting mindset since there aren't a lot of resources to help learn the process.

Comment: many thanks :) and great trouble-shooting tips!! I agree, my hack is not worth it if it's not processed like a react component, I'll find another way.