# Stripped out THEAD, TBODY, TR HTML elements from a Custom Table slot

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to learn VueJS. I'm still at the beginner level, so please excuse any misunderstandings.

I have a `.vue` file, which renders a custom table element.

```html
<template>
    <table v-bind:class="classes">
        <slot></slot>
    </table>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                styles: {
                    separator: 'separator',
                    solid: 'bg',
                    bg: 'bg'
                }
            };
        },
        props: {
            type: { default: 'separator' },
            theme: { default: 'primary' }
        },
        computed: {
            classes: function () {
                return `table m-table m-table--head-${this.styles[this.type]}-${this.theme}`;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

In my HTML file that is trying to create the template, it looks like this:

```html
<custom-table type="solid" theme="primary">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Value 1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</custom-table>
```

But when the page renders, all the html in the `<slot>` is stripped out, leaving only the text:

[image]

If I call `$vm0.$slots.defaults[0].elm`, all i get is the `text`, no HTML, no `<thead>` etc.

I've searched online, for `vuejs2 stripping out html from slots` and can't find anything relating to *why* it's happening.

I understand that my `.vue` file might not be perfect at the moment, I'm just trying to get the basics.

Any help, pointing me in the right direction as to why it's stripping out the HTML (or what else might be) is appreciated.

Comment: Speculating here, but it may be possible that you're encountering the `<thead>` and `<tbody>` elements being hoisted out as invalid content due to the expectation of their being a `<table>` wrapping them. See this section on [DOM Parsing Caveats](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#DOM-Template-Parsing-Caveats).

Comment: Good shout, I'll try it's suggestion :) Thanks!

Comment: @DigitalDrifter answer has already been posted, but the link you provided was a helpful answer as well. If you want to post it as an answer, I'll happily upvote it :)

Comment: No worries, glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is due to a restriction in HTML: table children (like `<thead>`, `<tr>`, etc.) can only appear within a `<table>`, even for a Custom Element.

The official workaround to use a custom table is to use the HTML attribute [`is`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/is), which is supported by Vue:

```html
<table is="custom-table" type="solid" theme="primary">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Value 1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

See [vue.js: what's the difference between <component :is="comp-name"/> and <div :is="comp-name"/>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50619025/vue-js-whats-the-difference-between-component-is-comp-name-and-div-is/50620292#50620292)

Comment: So is this what we're doing now instead of marking duplicates?

Comment: @Derek: not necessarily. I understand your confusion if I just add a link to an answer with similar content. In this case I considered that while that answer is relevant to this question as well, the questions are not equivalent. I could not find a suitable equivalent question with a quick search, even though it is a well known caveat (I would be happy to find one, if you have any?). Furthermore, it is observed that in front end many people (hopefully not OP here) reject duplicate questions that do not exactly fit their case. I remember a post on Meta about it but could not find it.

Comment: Fair enough, just checking. Thanks for the explanation. Some of the meta stuff contradicts itself sometimes.