# How to show a different html element/tag based on supplied prop in VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In Vuejs a `<template>` can only contain one root element, but what to do if you want to render different html element based on a prop?

**For example,** I have a `<heading>` component which I want to show/render `<h1>` if title prop, `prop: {title: {type: String, required: true}}` is **`title`**, and show/render `<h3>` if it is **`subtitle`**

And that reminds me, what if I want to do this for all `h` tags ? I mean based on prop condition, show one of these `<h1> to <h6>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `is` attribute will allow you to dynamically render whatever html element (or custom component - needs to be imported and registered though) you need. You can use it for example like this:

```
<template>
  <template :is="headingType">
    {{ headingContent }}
  </template>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      headingType: {
        type: String,
        default: 'h2' // you can pass anything from 'h1' to 'h6' here   
      },
      headingContent: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

More Info: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#is

Comment: I was researching and found that people are using `<component>` instead of `<template>` inside another `<template>` what's the difference?

Comment: To be honest I am not sure at the moment. Might be just a convention, because I even saw `div` being used in some codebases before. All of them get replaced by the specified element in the end. But this intrigues me now, so I will try to look for an answer when I get to my pc and  update my answer with my findings ;-)

Comment: @StudentX so I read about this today. You could look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50619025/vue-js-whats-the-difference-between-component-is-comp-name-and-div-is . For your purposes, this doesn't matter really ;)