# Conditional wrapper rendering in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, components

I'm making a link/button component which either can have a button or an anchor wrapper, a  text and an optional icon. My template code below is currently rendering either an anchor or a button (with the exact same content) based on an if statement on the wrapper element, resulting in duplicate code.

```
<template>
    <a v-if="link" v-bind:href="url" class="btn" :class="modifier" :id="id" role="button" :disabled="disabled">
        {{buttonText}}
        <svg class="icon" v-if="icon" :class="iconModifier">
            <use v-bind="{ 'xlink:href':'#sprite-' + icon }"></use>
        </svg>
    </a>
    <button v-else type="button" class="btn" :class="modifier" :id="id" :disabled="disabled">
        {{buttonText}}
        <svg class="icon" v-if="icon" :class="iconModifier">
            <use v-bind="{ 'xlink:href':'#sprite-' + icon }"></use>
        </svg>
    </button>
</template>
```

Is there a more clean way for wrapping my `buttonText` and icon inside either an anchor or button?

Comment: Yes you can use `is` attribute to do that. I have answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58892537/how-to-show-a-different-html-element-tag-based-on-supplied-prop-in-vuejs/58892674#58892674 . Check it, there is a code example there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved my issue by intensive Google-ing! Found [this issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/6358) regarding Vue on Github which pointed me in the right direction.

### Small piece of backstory

I'm using Vue in combination with Storybook to build a component library in which a button can either be a button or an anchor. All buttons look alike (apart from color) and can be used for submitting or linking. To keep my folder structure ordered, I would like a solution that generates a multiple buttons types (with or without link) from one single file.

### Solution

Using [computed properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) I'm able to "calculate" the necessary tag, based on the `url` property of my component. When a `url` is passed, I know that my button has to link to another page. If there is no `url` property it should submit something or preform a custom click handler (not in the sample code below).

I've created the `returnComponentTag` computed property to avoid placing any complex or bulky logic (like my original solution) in my template. This returns either an `a` or a `button` tag based on the existence of the `url` property.

Next, as suggested by ajobi, using the `:is` attribute I'm able to define the component tag based on the result of my computed property. Below a stripped sample of my final (and working) solution:

```
<template>
    <component :is="returnComponentTag" v-bind:href="url ? url : ''" class="btn" :class="modifier" :id="id">
        {{buttonText}}
    </component>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "Button",
    props: {
        id: {
            type: Number
        },
        buttonText: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            default: "Button"
        },
        modifier: {
            type: String,
            default: "btn-cta-01"
        },
        url: {
            type: String,
            default: ""
        }
    }, 
    computed: {
        returnComponentTag() {
            return this.url ? "a" : "button"
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the wrapping element into a dedicated component.

```
<template>
    <a v-if="link" v-bind:href="url" class="btn" :class="modifier" :id="id" role="button" :disabled="disabled">
        <slot></slot>
    </a>
    <button v-else type="button" class="btn" :class="modifier" :id="id" :disabled="disabled">
        <slot></slot>
    </button>
</template>

// You would use it like this

<SomeComponent /* your props here */ >
    {{buttonText}}
    <svg class="icon" v-if="icon" :class="iconModifier">
        <use v-bind="{ 'xlink:href':'#sprite-' + icon }"></use>
    </svg>
</SomeComponent>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing this. Two examples would be the following based on the point of view:

1. You are defining two different components (Button or Anchor) and want to use a wrapper to render either one of them.

   - You could seperate the Wrapper Content into two components so that the wrapper only decides on which of the components to render (either the Button or the Anchor).
   - The problem with this approach could be you will have doubled code for methods and styling for the button and anchor component.
2. You are defining the content as a component and use the wrapper to define what to wrap the content in.

   - See Answer of https://stackoverflow.com/a/60052780/11930769

It would be great to know, why you would want to achive this. Maybe there are better solutions for your usecase. Cheers!